# mat-table showing error and not displaying values

Tags: angular, angular-material2

material angular table to display values from restapi service.

using angular5 typescript.

getting values from service in array format

```
<mat-table #table >
          <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
              <mat-header-cell> `ID` </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit of Visits"> {{visit.username}} 
               </mat-cell>
           </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="height">
        <mat-header-cell> ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit of Visits"> {{visit.height}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <mat-header-cell> Progress </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit"> {{visit.weight}}% </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
       <ng-container matColumnDef="patientnote">
        <mat-header-cell > Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit"> {{visit.patientnote}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="doctornote">
        <mat-header-cell > Color </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit"> {{visit.doctornote}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

    </mat-table>
```

and my typescript code here

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public Visits: any;

   public constructor(private location: Location, private http: Http, private router: Router){

       }

   public ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/visit')
    .map(result => ['result'])
    .subscribe(result => {

       this.Visits = result ;

        console.log('submit get click happend ' + this.Visits );

    });

  }
```

screenshot of error

[image]

i am new to material angular.please help me to fix it .
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is just a plain object, it should be an array of objects to generate inside ngFor in DOM.

Change your response to be array of objects, or push the object to an empty array.

Comment: Thank you for reply